# symfony2.1 EventSubscriberInterface error

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I've just followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html to the letter in order to make my file upload field show only on the 'new' form, not the 'edit' form.

```
 $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('file', 'file', array('required' => true)));
```

I get this error on the 'new' form, but the 'edit' form is fine. It's probably obvious to the experienced, but this is my first SF project, and I'm not sure why the cookbook tutorial resulted in an error for me.

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.
```

Could someone please clarify the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('file', 'file', array('required' => true)));
```

to

```
$form->add($this->factory->createNamed('file', 'file'));
```

fixed it.